# Third Party Controls for ASP.NET with Ajax Support

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Ours is an upcoming company, so we cannot buy two three third party controls and find out by ourselves which the best one is.(One of the better solutions)
We have a budget to buy just one.
So we would like to know which is third party control is the best to use in ASP.NET based on your experiences.

And also I definitely saw a question asked already here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215993/best-3rd-party-aspnet-grid-control

Still asking this because

1. Wanna know not just about grid, i wanna know about the whole set.
2. Didn't see many answers for that.

So please provide us some advice on how to proceed.
Our requirements are

1. Bug Free working
2. Speed
3. Good documentation
4. Excellent Support Team

Also is there a third party ListView?

Regards,

Naveen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all those requirements, there's only two companies to choose from: [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/).  Both have fantastic support and incredible ASP.NET products.  They release often, and are known to be constantly adding new controls.  I had to decide between the two about a year ago, and went with DevExpress because of the productivity tools included.

The difference I see between these two companies and larger competitors like Infragistics is they are dedicated to making the best quality and best performing products possible.

Comment: @Jeff Schumacher,
Telerik and DevExpress were at top of my list.
I would like to ask about the comment about "Infragistics".
What made you say that? Just to know cos these three were my top priorities...

Comment: @naveen - I compared them at the same time as the other two. The controls were slow, missing features, and unintuitive in their api's and designers. Perhaps their stuff has gotten better, maybe they started over on their code. It was after all a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

We use Telerik. The overall experience is good. For us, the main pitfall is page size. E.g., single combo-box with 50 items may generate 40kb of HTML!

Answer (score 1):

We've been using Telerik for some time now in my company.  I believe we've renewed our subscription for the third time this year, and they just keep getting better and better!  Their support is fantastics also!

I haven't used any DevExpress ASP.NET controls so I can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

I would add Componentone to the list of good companyes who make great components. Check out their studio for Asp.Net package. Full of nice components. Most of them use Ajax. You can check out samples of all components on their homepage and you can download and try before buy.

The licenses are developer-based and you dont have to pay anything for redist.
They have great support and lots of samples and code so its easy to consume the components.

www.componentone.com

http://componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioASPNET/